# Unable to record Hybrid App using JMeter

Tags: android, https, proxy, jmeter, hybrid

I am trying to record an Hybrid App (Native+Web) of Android using the HTTP proxy recording option of J Meter. When i access that app it is taking to HTTPS site and from there it is not recorded in J Meter. Page is showing blank and not directing to any page

Saw most of the articles, but still i am unable to record the HTTPS Site, Please assist me

Answer (score 0):

As per [Load Testing Mobile Apps. But Made Easy.](http://blazemeter.com/blog/load-testing-mobile-apps-made-easy) guide:

> Note that Android supports only HTTP proxy. If your application uses an HTTPS connection, then you may use an additional application that performs with HTTPS proxing.

So I believe that you need something like [ProxyDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.proxydroid&hl=en) or similar

Comment: Hi Dmitri,

When i see the previous HTTP request, i am able to see that CSRF Token is sent with request, but when i go the next HTTP Request Samplers response, i see the below error. 

{"detail": "CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing or incorrect."}

what could be the reason and what should i do to handle this ??